# Strange get request in node.js express

Tags: node.js, express

My express server send this request, but I don't know which file send it and why it response with 404. Please help me track this down:

```
GET /sw-import.js?baseURI=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fplatinum-sw%2Fplatinum-sw-register.html&clientsClaim=true&defaultCacheStrategy=networkFirst&importscript=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fplatinum-sw%2Fbootstrap%2Fsw-toolbox-setup.js&importscriptLate=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fbower_components%2Fplatinum-sw%2Fbootstrap%2Fsw-toolbox-setup.js&precache=&skipWaiting=true&version=1.0 404 6.503 ms - 255
```

Comment: Can't help you if you don't show your express route in your Node.js code.

Comment: Where are your routes?

Answer (score 0):

The request means service worker is registered in the scope http://localhost:3000/
You can verify whether it's running by entering `chrome://inspect/#service-workers` or see the registration using `chrome://serviceworker-internals`